# Vault Admin Policy not allowed to create new policies

Tags: hashicorp-vault

I'm trying to follow the standard pattern: root - admin - user for Hashicorp Vault.

Basically: root creates one admin policy. Then my admin needs to be able to create limited policies for new user.

However, even with all access to `/sys`, my admin get a permission denied on creating new policies.

Here is my admin policy:

```
path "pki/issue/admin" { capabilities = ["create", "update"]}
path "pki/roles/" {capabilities = ["create", "update"]}
path "pki/issue/" {capabilities = ["create", "update"]}
path "auth/token/*" {capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete"]}
path "auth/token/lookup-self" {capabilities = ["read"]}
path "auth/token/renew-self" {capabilities = ["update"]}
path "auth/token/revoke-self" {capabilities = ["update"]}
path "auth/token/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list", "sudo"]
}
path "sys/auth/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "sudo"]
}
path "sys/policy" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list", "sudo"]
}
path "sys/policy/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list", "sudo"]
}
```

```
$ curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer admintoken' http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/auth/token/lookup-self | jq .data.policies
[
  "admin"
]
```

```
$ curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer adminsecret' http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/policy/agent01 -d '{"name": "test", "policy": "path \"auth/token/lookup-self\" { capabilities = [\"read\"]}"}'
{"errors":["permission denied"]}
```

Am I missing something essential here? I'd rather avoid spreading my root token to my backend server just to create basic policies to new users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what version of vault are you using ?

I've tried this simple policy and it seems to work:

```
$ vault policy read pol
path "sys/policy/*" {
  capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "list", "sudo"]
}
```

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $(vault token create -field token -policy pol)" http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/policy/agent01 -d '{"name": "test", "policy": "path \"auth/token/lookup-self\" { capabilities = [\"read\"]}"}' -vvv
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8200 (#0)
> POST /v1/sys/policy/agent01 HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8200
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer s.FJ7MVrAZMcUAh1xmYWEWfxyZ
> Content-Length: 90
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 90 out of 90 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 204 No Content
< Cache-Control: no-store
< Content-Type: application/json
< Date: Sun, 02 Feb 2020 12:02:19 GMT
<
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

```
$ vault policy list
agent01
agent0111
default
pol
root
```

```
$ vault version
Vault v1.3.0
```

Comment: Thank you, sometimes the problem is somewhere between the chair and the keyboard... I was using the wrong token.